# Create my custom like artisan for my own custom php framework

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm working on a custome PHP framework for learning propose,
Now I need to create custom cli for my framework and I want to make it in different composer package to be used and updated separately.

**The Problem is:**

How I can use the separated cli and its commands in my framework as if its internal commands in the framework ?! Or in other words How I can create a file like artisan in Laravel for my cli package ?

**For example:**

In cli composer package this is how to run the command

```
$bin/console hello-world
```

I want to be able to use this command in my framework after require the cli package

OR

Create a custom file like artisan named commander and use it like that

```
commander hello-world
```

Comment: Laravel's `artisan` command is just a simple executable `php` script without the `.php` extension. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan

Comment: Ok I know that but how I can you the cli package commands in my framework

Comment: This is a broad question and highly opinable, my advice is to look in the laravel source code to learn how to do and, when you ancouter a specific programming problem, ask here for help.

Comment: The answer is: you can't. If you execute `php artisan list`, then there must be a file called `artisan` in the current directory from where you run this. You can surely create a file that only acts as wrapper to another executable (and redirects input to `vendor/bin/console`), but you need a file in the project directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `symfony/console`.

Installation:

```
composer require symfony/console
```

Create a file: `bin/console`

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// load all commands here from an external php file
$commands  = [
    \App\Console\ExampleCommand::class,
];

$application = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Application();

foreach ($commands as $class) {
    if (!class_exists($class)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Class %s does not exist', $class));
    }
    $command = new $class();
    $application->add($command);
}

$application->run();
```

ExampleCommand.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * Command.
 */
class ExampleCommand extends AbstractCommand
{
    /**
     * Configure.
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        $this->setName('example');
        $this->setDescription('A sample command');
    }

    /**
     * Execute command.
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     *
     * @return int integer 0 on success, or an error code
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Hello console');

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bin/console example
```

Output:

```
Hello console
```